# How to get informed about scrolling over the top of a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scrollview

Can somebody help me? I have an `activity` with a `ViewPager` in it. The Pages (Fragments) uses vertical `ScrollView`s. How can i realize, that a user who wants to update its contents can do it like in other apps e.g. Facebook? I mean, if the user is on the top of a `ScrollView` and he try to scroll up again, then there should open a loading-animation on the top of the `ScrollView` and a function loads data from a web sever....

So how i can get notified about the scroll up gesture of the user ?

I know that i will need a "invisible" `view` above the `scrollView` wich became visible when the user scroll "over the top" of the `scrollView`. The Animation and the dataexchange with the web server still aren't a problem - i will do it in an async task. My only question: where i have to listen on, to get informed about the scroll gesture *over the top* of the `ScrollView`?

Thanks,
Greets

PS: Sorry for my english - i am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnScrollViewListener** her is [example](http://www.nicholasmelnick.com/entries/104) for how to use it

Comment: Thanks for the link, i've tried the given example and get it to work, but unfortunatelly it doesn't solve my problem. With this example i can get the position of scrollview, but i can't get information about the user wants to scroll "over the top" of the list, i just get information about scroll right to the top. But i found something on YouTube, hope i can translate it for me and bring it to work, because it seems to be exactly the thing i need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lcBx4KVUVk